# Compute 34 million line, my jupyter lab kernel is dead

Tags: python, bigdata, jupyter

I have 34 million row and only have a column. I want to split string value in dataframe into some column but it took a long time and my jupyter lab kernel is dead while processing it.

Here is my sample dataset (df):

```
Log
Apr  4 20:30:33 100.51.100.254 dns,packet user: --- got query from 10.5.14.243:30648:
Apr  4 20:30:33 100.51.100.254 dns,packet user: id:78a4 rd:1 tc:0 aa:0 qr:0 ra:0 QUERY 'no error'
Apr  4 20:30:33 100.51.100.254 dns,packet user: question: tracking.intl.miui.com:A:IN
Apr  4 20:30:33 dns user: query from 9.5.10.243: #4746190 tracking.intl.miui.com. A
```

I want to split it into four column using this code:

```
df1 = df['Log'].str.split(n=3, expand=True)
df1.columns=['Month','Date','Time','Log']
df1.head()
```

Here is the result that i expected

```
     Month Date      Time                                              Log
0      Apr    4  20:30:33  100.51.100.254 dns,packet user: --- go...
1      Apr    4  20:30:33  100.51.100.254 dns,packet user: id:78a...
2      Apr    4  20:30:33  100.51.100.254 dns,packet user: questi...
3      Apr    4  20:30:33  dns transjakarta: query from 9.5.10.243: #474...
4      Apr    4  20:30:33  100.51.100.254 dns,packet user: --- se...
```

When I use sample 800k rows, it success. but, when I apply it in full data, the kernel was dead.

is there solution to handle this? maybe using dask or swifter?

Comment: python2 or python3? is that all your code?

Comment: There is no reason why isn't work for 34 million when it is for 800K, This looks more of a memory issue to me. Try running the same code from a terminal from a upgraded machine

Comment: maybe you should read only part of data (chunk), modify it and write in another file - and then read next part of data. If you use `read_csv()` then you can read with `read_csv( ... , chunk=number_of_rows)`

Comment: @Netwave Python 3, it's all code for split it into 4 column that i want

Comment: @OctavianWibawaReksa, the problem is that you are loading the whole 34M lines in memmory. You need to do it lazyly or by chunks.